# gomonkey applyFunc not effect

Tags: go

my code like this

Expected: real function
Actual:   mock function

```
func A() {
    fmt.Println("real function")
}
func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    gomonkey.ApplyFunc(A, func() {
        fmt.Println("mock function")
    })
    A()
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and I think you may have your "expected" and "actual" backwards.

Comment: How are you running the tests? The [gomonkey documentation](https://github.com/agiledragon/gomonkey#test-method) includes a specific set of optoins that must be passed to `go test` for things to work as expected.